# Limit of exponential function using natural log and change of variable without L'Hopital

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

$$ \lim_{x\to \:0}\left(\frac{a^x-1}{x}\right) $$
 I know the answer to this is $$\ln \left(a\right)$$ but I don't know how to reach that answer without L'Hopital. 
I just know the first step (given to me like a hint): use change of variable $$ a^x-1\:=\:u $$

But how when I use this I reach the non conclusive $$\lim _{u\to 0}\left(\frac{u}{\log _a\left(u+1\right)}\right)$$
 or the $$\lim \:_{u\to \:0}\left(\frac{u\:\ln \left(a\right)}{\ln \left(u+1\right)}\right)$$

I know I'm doing this wrong so I would like some orientation on how to tackle problems like these.
Is there any relation to the ones solved with the definition of Euler? Those I know how to manipulate the expressions to have them look like it. 
Beforehand thank you very much.

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use? [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?

Comment: It follows as a consequence if you define $\int_{1}^{a}\frac{1}{x}dx=lna$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've reached a perfectly conclusive point since
$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\ln(1+u)}u=1$$
is a high-school standard limit.

It is actually the limit of the *rate of variation* of the function $\ln x$, starting from $x=1$, so that its limit is just the derivative of the log at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use here the definition of $e$.

Indeed, since $\ln$ is a continuous function we obtain:
$$\lim_{u\rightarrow0}\frac{u}{\ln(1+u)}=\lim_{u\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\ln(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}}}=\frac{1}{\ln\lim\limits_{u\rightarrow0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}}}=\frac{1}{\ln{e}}=1.$$

Answer (score 1):

What you did is good.

I do not know if, in this context, *limit-without-lhopital* excludes Taylor series. If not, you could have more than the limit itself writing
$$a^x=e^{x \log(a)}=1+x \log (a)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 \log ^2(a)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ which makes
$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\log (a)+\frac{1}{2} x \log ^2(a)+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and also how it is approached.

Let for example $a=\pi$ and $x=\frac 1 {10}$. The exact value $10 \left(\sqrt[10]{\pi }-1\right)\approx 1.21282$ while the above truncated expression would give $\frac{1}{20} \log (\pi ) (20+\log (\pi ))\approx 1.21025$.